# Who is hosting the remote disc when reinstalling OS from remote disc

Tags: macos, install, remote-disc

I have a used mac book pro and have to reinstall the OS from remote disc. My question is: is the remote disc in this case (OS install) hosted by Apple or is it hosted by some other users' laptops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Remote Disk](https://support.apple.com/HT203973) is a method for sharing another user's CD/DVD drive over your local network, if your own Mac doesn't have an optical drive. It's not a method for installing an OS onto a blank Mac.

For that you would use Internet Recovery to reinstall your OS from scratch;
hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>   at the boot chimes.
This will load the image directly from Apple.

See Apple KB: [How to reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT204904)

Comment: According to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2002127 it can be use to RE-install Mac OS, but as Tetsujin said, not onto a blank Mac.  (Obviously if the Mac is blank, there's no Finder window to hold the remote icon!!)